# How to access JSON element in HTML with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Hello everyone I hope anyone of you can help me. I just started with PY.
I am trying to acces a JSON element within the HTML and then log it.

This is the HTML and I want to get `currencyCode":"EUR", "value":50`, these two things.

```html
 <!-- BOOTSTRAP -->
<script type="application/json" id="bootstrap">

{
    "context": {
        "env": "PRODUCTION"
    },
    "checkoutUserProfile": {
        "addressBook": {
            "addresses": []
        },
        "wallet": {
            "paymentCards": []
        },
        "sessionStatus": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
    },
    "checkoutConfig": {
        "showEmailListSubscribeOption": true,
        "emailListOptInByDefault": true,
        "userAccountsConfig": {
            "loginAllowed": false,
            "signupAllowed": false
        },
        "paymentConfig": {
            "gatewayConnected": true,
            "testMode": false,
            "allowTestModePaymentOverride": false,
            "stripeConnected": true,
            "paypalConnected": true,
            "paypalSandbox": false,
            "paypalMerchantId": "BQHKFVWZ5DJSN",
            "applePayEnabled": true,
            "paypalEnabled": true,
            "afterpayAvailable": false,
            "afterpayMinValueSubunits": 0,
            "afterpayMaxValueSubunits": 0,
            "klarnaAvailable": false,
            "trialMode": false,
            "storeCurrency": "EUR",
            "paymentAmountConstraints": {
                "minimum": {
                    "currencyCode": "EUR",
                    "value": 50,
                    "decimalValue": "0.50",
                    "fractionalDigits": 2
                }
            },
            "acceptedPaymentCardTypes": ["MASTERCARD", "VISA", "AMEX"]
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

This was my unfortunatley unsuccessful attempt :

```py
pricetotal = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser").find("script", {"id":"bootstrap"})["checkoutConfig"]["value"]
print(f"Price is: {pricetotal}")
```

I hope someone can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This much is correct:

```
pricetotal = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser").find("script", {"id":"bootstrap"})
```

That gets you a `bs4.element.Tag` that contains the matched `<script>` element. You can't get the `checkoutConfig` key from that because it's just an HTML element; you need to:

1. Extract the text
2. Deserialize the data from JSON into python data structures

We can extract the text by accessing the `text` attribute:

```
>>> pricetotal.text
'\n\n  {\n    "context": {"env":"PRODUCTION"},\n    ...
```

And we can deserialize it using the `json` module...except that what
you've pasted in your question isn't actually valid JSON (it looks
like you've truncated the text).

If it *was* valid JSON, you could do something like this:

```
>>> data = json.loads(pricetotal.text)
>>> data['checkoutConfig']
{'showEmailListSubscribeOption': True, 'emailListOptInByDefault': True, 'userAccountsConfig': {'loginAllowed': False, 'signupAllowed': False}, 'paymentConfig': {'gatewayConnected': True, 'testMode': False, 'allowTestModePaymentOverride': False, 'stripeConnected': True, 'paypalConnected': True, 'paypalSandbox': False, 'paypalMerchantId': 'BQHKFVWZ5DJSN', 'applePayEnabled': True, 'paypalEnabled': True, 'afterpayAvailable': False, 'afterpayMinValueSubunits': 0, 'afterpayMaxValueSubunits': 0, 'klarnaAvailable': False, 'trialMode': False, 'storeCurrency': 'EUR', 'paymentAmountConstraints': {'minimum': {'currencyCode': 'EUR', 'value': 50, 'decimalValue': '0.50', 'fractionalDigits': 2}}, 'acceptedPaymentCardTypes': ['MASTERCARD', 'VISA', 'AMEX']}}
```